# Burninate/Retag/Synonym [music]+[audio]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

In my opinion, [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) (x1480) should be retagged (or should be a synonym of audio) or burninated.

Reasons:

- Music is not the right tag for software-specific sounds. Audio it is.
- Even the tag description states that.
- 1/6 of questions already tagged with [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- ...

What should we do with it?

Comment: Rather than burninate shouldn't we be making them synonyms and then merging?

Comment: This is getting out of hand. Next time they will want us to burn `[books]`.

Comment: Sounds good. I don't have enough reputation, that's why I asked rather than making a synonym.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Why not? Now that we got [E-books].

Comment: I'm not sure they should be synonyms. To me, music means more than audio. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180858/procedural-music-generation-techniques seems the perfect example of something that should be tagged as music, but definitely not audio.

Comment: @Hecksa, and then closed by any current standard...

Comment: (as of 2021:) This has just been bumped by an edit. The [tag:music] tag has already been burninated, so this Q&A is moot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The \[music\] has finally stopped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362928/the-music-has-finally-stopped)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here seems to be a simple matter of the tag being misused on a large scale. [The tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/music/info) does a pretty good job of explaining the distinction, in my opinion, and the distinction is certainly one worth making. Music is absolutely an area in which individuals could be considered experts.

I think there's a large number of questions out there that do need the music tag removed. I *don't* think the music tag needs burnination in general.

There's nothing wrong with the tag, but there *is* something wrong with the way it's being used.

Answer (score 2):

Like in any good community system, consensus can change.  The [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag is being burninated right now: [The [music] tag is in the process of being burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362928/the-music-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated)