# The [music] has finally stopped

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   Questions tagged with [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) *can* live without it. They usually refer to a music-related *application*, which doesn't have any added value when it has the [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   [Most](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180858) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31782580) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974531) [top questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music?sort=votes&pageSize=15) of this tag are off-topic and can be closed.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   No. [Most](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48605196) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48583980) the questions I came through are general and refer to **music applications**, not **programming**.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Mmm... I think so.

So, what do you think?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to replace it with a `sound-generation` tag?

Comment: @AyushGupta depends on the questions. Also, why should a question about a program which only purpose is generate sound, does not have the name of the program and instead something vague?

Comment: Agree with @Braiam -- You can't just replace.  It could be related to `midi`, `audio-streaming`, etc.

Comment: Technically creating music with code rather than a program is a thing... I don't see it happening that many questions will be about that topic though. It'd probably be more under a topic of 64k/4k programming.

Comment: Tag was created "[9 years, 6 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/music/info)" -- wow, now I'd call that *oldies radio!* (I'll get my coat).

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +82/-1, No answers.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not start removing the tag from questions until the community has decided whether to move forward with the burnination or not.

Comment: Official music video of this request https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yd8jh9QYfEs

Comment: @BhargavRao: This question was asked in February.  How long do we have to wait?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I usually wait for 36~48 hours after featuring to unfeature and decide whether to continue with the burnination or not. I get it that the decision is quite clear in this case, but just in case a top user in that tag has a word or two to say. (Just to put the backlog of burn requests into perspective, [movement] was [featured] and burninated, 5 years 4 months and 600 new questions after it was requested)

Comment: @Braiam It looks *the day the [music] died* is upon us: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yHTpGog0IY

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: 127/-7, A1 (saying Yes): +13/-1, A2 (saying Yes): +28/-1, A3 (saying Yes): +10/0, A4 (saying Yes): +7/0. The community has voted in favor of the burnination.

Comment: I think that [music] questions are being too often closed as "too broad" now for some questions that are actually quite specific -- I ask the community to more often retag than close for too broad (most of the off-topic for recommending library closes have been perfect).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use [juce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juce) for questions related to the cross-platform GUI library, Juce.
- Use [midi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/midi) for questions related to the MIDI protocol.
- Use [music-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music-notation) for generating or processing scores or guitar tabs.
- Use [music-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music-theory) for algorithmic/software approaches to music theory including identifying chords.
- Use [playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playback) for just playing a sound.
- Use [signal-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing) for approaches to extracting pitch or other information from a wave or sound file.
- Use [audio-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-player) for more complex software (up to DAWs)
- Use custom tags like [android-mediaplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediaplayer), [mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mp3), [wav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wav) or [html5-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-audio) when relevant

## Progress:

The [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=music),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmusic%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmusic%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmusic%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmusic%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185759)

#### Details:

[image]

#### Large Tag Guidance

Remember that [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) has more than 2400 questions. Therefore do not go through all of them! Retag the ones which are worth saving (usually the top voted posts) and vote to close the unsalvageable questions (usually the very low scored).

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag —just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: "At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the music tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption." -- I thought the burnination process only deleted closed, tagged, and **negative score** questions.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert, for large tags, yes. For others, no. This is a large tag, so only the  closed negative scored questions will be deleted. The entire thing is written for normal tags. The different method for large tags started very recently, and we need to update the main meta.

Answer (score 37):

Having reviewed a few pages of questions tagged [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music), I don't see anything that is not better serviced with more precise tags such as [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) or [midi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/midi) or [audio-streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-streaming) or [sound-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sound-generation) or similar. There doesn't seem to be any field of knowledge, expertise, or interest that the tag helps target. Even interest in music in general doesn't tie the questions together in any meaningful way that improves the taxonomy of the site or help people navigate to things they are interested in.

Let it burn.

Comment: I remember answering a few questions about waveform programming, but they were all tagged `audio` not `music`. I guess I have no objection.

Comment: _"Let it burn, let it burn, gotta let it burn.... deep down you know it’s best.."_ - Usher.    

 Just bringing it full circle with some music

Answer (score 12):

I write music, I write code for music, whether using midi, audio, and any kind of synthesis.

I don't think [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) is enough on its own. The sheer amount of different topics (midi, audio, different subtypes of synthesis) will almost always make something with just [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) too broad or unclear. Lots of them will not even belong to SO. So having [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) may even be worrying because of the question belong to stats.SE, maths.SE or software engineering.SE

If one were to use the tag to find an interested topic, then again, the tag would not be precise enough because if I search something on music, it actually be related to [juce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juce), or [midi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/midi), or something else.

So let it burn.

Answer (score 11):

A quick look at the tag description for [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) makes it seem like a reasonable tag and there are perhaps a lot of questions misusing it.  However, when looking at the two examples of "good use of the music tag" questions in the description (one closed, the other should be as off topic), and the top questions for the tag (several are closed, others look to be either off topic, don't need the music tag, or just don't benefit from it) it would seem that it isn't adding anything useful to the questions.

Much as I like to listen to music, I say we should let the [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag burn.

Answer (score 9):

I have been trying for some time to set the music tag to refer only to those questions that refer to computer approaches to music that cannot be applied to any audio/sound file or to the specifics of midi, such as generating music notation or computational music theory.  (I wrote the current tag description for music).

But it seems to be a losing battle, and it'd probably be easier to make [music-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music-theory) and [music-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music-notation) tags -- they won't have nearly as many questions tagged with it as "music" currently does, but it'd be much easier for someone to find those questions any how.

I'd be happy to let it burn, but I'd like to try to take some time to retag the small percentage of properly tagged questions with the new tags first.

Comment: Feel free to join in the burnination effort by retagging those small percentage of questions that you are familiar with. We do spend 2 to 3 weeks cleaning the tag before removing the tag from the system.

Comment: Thanks!  I've created [music-notation[ and [music-theory] but I'm a bit low on rep. to get automatic edits accepted, so I'm retagging as I can. thx!

Comment: Remember to not suggest just retags, try to correct all the issues with the post and add the tag. Also add the retag guidance to the CW answer, so that others also know to use that tag while they're cleaning up the [music] tag.

Comment: Thanks to all who have helped with the moving on [music-notation] and giving wiki descriptions to [music-notation] and [music-theory] -- most of the questions with the retagging to these categories were high quality questions and didn't need editing.

Comment: Someone seems to have deleted the [tag:music-theory] -- strange...