# The [music] is back with followers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Going though the tags today I noticed the [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag was back [after being burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362928/the-music-has-finally-stopped). The one thing that caught my eye is even though the tag was burned and was newly created, it already had 2.1k watchers which I'm assuming was a carry over from before it was burned.

[image]

Is this the intended behavior for a burned tag? Since everything else is wiped clean, it would seem that the tag should have started over with no followers/watchers.

Comment: The followers issue is that the table that keeps followers doesn't store an id-like, but the actual tag name. So, when the tag is removed from one side, it isn't from the other.

Comment: Drove my Chevy to the levee but the levee was dry. [[meta-tag:status-norepro]] Someone obviously retagged it. Makes it hard to have a [[meta-tag:discussion]].

Comment: The band's back together, groupies making new [music].

Comment: We hate fun. And music.

Comment: That will just happen over and over again, programmers do like to writing code to produce music.  One of the saddest burninations I've seen, I burn a candle for @MusiGenesis, the top-rated answerer in the tag.  Contributors like him are very special, no room at the inn anymore for them.

Comment: i assume making it an alias of audio was considered last time round? and it's meaningless without knowing if it's being recorded, processed, or played!