# Burn / Synonym the [music-player] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, clean-up

There are two tags that serve almost the same function the [audio-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-player) and the [music-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music-player) tags.

It is unlikely that [audio-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-player) would not play music or a [music-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music-player) that would not play other forms of audio.

The [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) tag itself was just recently [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362928/the-music-has-finally-stopped)
 although it has recently come [back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382460/the-music-is-back-with-followers).

There is a recent request to re-tag a lot of [player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/player) questions that also had [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) into [audio-player](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284647/the-player-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated?cb=1#284741) which is more general.

There are 616 questions in the [music-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music-player) tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a small issue in here. There seems to be a lot of questions tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), and there exists a [android-music-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-music-player) tag already. I'm not that aware if Android's Music Player needs its own tag, but seems like it is being used quite consistently there, so I would leave it. The other questions all look like related to Audio Players, and a synonym would seem fit. My idea here would be to

1. Mass retag [music-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music-player) questions which also have the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag to [android-music-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-music-player).
2. Synonymize [music-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music-player) to [audio-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-player).

In this way, we will be sure that we have disambiguated the tag before synonymizing it.

Comment: this probably should be `android-mediaplayer`. tag `android-music-player` might have been introduced by users not knowing it's actual name. see [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer).

Comment: There is a [tag:android-mediaplayer] tag as well, @Martin. Would it make sense to merge the two tags?

Comment: the `android-mediaplayer` should be the primary one. just check a few questions tagged differently... they might in most cases mean the same thing (since the framework does not have a music player). there's also `vlc-android` (open source) ... which could be understood as an "android media player".